# How to set timezone for my application deployed on RUN@Cloud

Tags: cloudbees

I am using the cloud bees to run our application. But the Time is being shown in GMT. What we want is IST ?

Here is the sample code :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
TimeZone istTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"); 
cal.setTimeZone(istTime); 
Date chkOut = cal.getTime(); 
startTripMapperObj.setRentalStartTime(chkOut); 
Date chkOut2 = startTripMapperObj.getRentalStartTime(); 
RentalTrip r = new RentalTrip();
```

This is the output :

```
Trip Check In   Wed Aug 15 14:34:20 GMT 2012 
Trip Check Out  Wed Aug 15 14:12:00 GMT 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

by default the timezone is GMT - for java apps you can set the timezone yourself (I have seen some people do it in a servlet context listener so it runs on app startup time).

If you are using the cloudbees SDK, you can also set jvmTimeZone=XXX parameter which will then set it for all instance of that application from then on.