# Not able to change JVM timezone using Cloudbees SDK

Tags: cloudbees

I found this question: [How to set timezone for my application deployed on RUN@Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972149/how-to-set-timezone-for-my-application-deployed-on-runcloud) where it is suggested to use the jvmTimeZone but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I have tried:

```
bees config:set -RjvmTimeZone=Europe/Berlin
bees config:set -jvmTimeZone=Europe/Berlin
```

but `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone()` still returns "GMT"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jvmTimeZone is a Platform parameter, can only be set using app:deploy / app:update

```
   bees app:update jvmTimeZone=Europe/Berlin
```